# Start matlab for loop from non zero value

Tags: matlab, for-loop, brute-force

I have the code below in which I am trying to start the "number_panels" and "number_turbines" for loop from a non zero number.

More specifically I am trying for 3000 to 4000 "number_panels" with 500 panel interval
and from 5 to 8 "number_turbines" with one turbine interval
i.e

```
number_of_days = 2;

for number_panels = 3000:500:4000 % range of PV panel units examined

for number_turbines = 5:8  % range of wind turbine units examined


    for h=1:24 %# hours

       for d = 1:number_of_days %# which day



            n = h + 24*(d-1);
            % hourly_deficit_1(...,..., h, d)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %


            hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, h,d) = hourly_annual_demand(n) - (hourly_annual_PV(n)*number_panels) - (hourly_annual_WT(n)*number_turbines);% hourly power deficit (RES supply with demand)


            if hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, h,d)< 0 % zero out negative hourly deficit values (this is power surplus from RES)

                hourly_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1, h,d) = 0;

            end
```

When I do this I get a size(hourly_deficit) = 4001,9,24,2 whereas I am expecting and trying to achieve a 3,4,24,2 size. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of the variable `number_panels` starts at 3000 instead of 0 or 1.  Thus when you index a matrix with that variable as the index value Matlab thinks you are wanting the 3001st index and thus gives you a matrix that is 3000 zeros with the 3001st being set to what you ask.

If you follow the loop into it's next cycle the value of `number_panels` becomes 3500.  You now are indexing at 3501, based on your code.  This means that all of the places from 3002 to 3500 will be filled with zeros and 3501 will be set to whatever value you give it.

The same logic applies to `number_turbines`  The only difference is that you'll be indexing by 1 instead of by 500 like you are with `number_panels`.

If you want to get back to the size matrix you are expecting you'll need to modify the way you call the index values.  This could be done a number of ways.  You could have a counter within the for-loop or you could use modulus math.  Modulus math doesn't work well when you're using a step size that isn't `1`.  It also doesn't work when you get to the point where you have an index value that is a multiple of your starting index.

You'll have to work out what will work best for you in that arena.  Especially since you want to use a step size that isn't 1.  But for the `number_turbines` that goes from 5 to 8, you can simple index using `number_turbines - 5 + 1` or more concise `number_turbines-4`.

For clarity, here is the code you provided with the necessary tweaks to show the use of what was mentioned in the comments.  Please take note that you will need to modify the `-4` for the `number_turbines` index value should you start at something other than `5`.  Also note that you need to index the `number_panels` vector now since it's not a looped value.

Hope this helps!

```
number_of_days = 2;
number_panels = 3000:500:4000;

for idx_number_panels = 1:length(number_panels) % range of PV panel units examined

    for number_turbines = 5:8  % range of wind turbine units examined


        for h=1:24 %# hours

            for d = 1:number_of_days %# which day



                n = h + 24*(d-1);
                % hourly_deficit_1(...,..., h, d)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %


                hourly_deficit(idx_number_panels , number_turbines -4, h,d) = hourly_annual_demand(n) - (hourly_annual_PV(n)*number_panels(idx_number_panels)) - (hourly_annual_WT(n)*number_turbines);% hourly power deficit (RES supply with demand)


                if hourly_deficit(idx_number_panels, number_turbines -4, h,d)< 0 % zero out negative hourly deficit values (this is power surplus from RES)

                    hourly_deficit(idx_number_panels, number_turbines -4, h,d) = 0;

                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: ok so I have to use "number_panels" = 2999:500:3999? and if so how do I get rid of the zeros so that I can read the data set results easier. thank you

Comment: You'll have to be somewhat creative with that solution.  It honestly might be easier if you just have another variable that starts at 1 and indexs with each loop for `number_panels`.

Comment: This is where the dreaded `for panel_num=1:length(number_panels)` syntax does in fact make sense.

Comment: not sure I follow, the length(number_panels) should give a 3x1 vector of 3000;3500;4000 number of panels?

Comment: I updated with a code example for you to follow.  Hopefully it works as it's just simply typed up and not tested.

Comment: thanks but the above is multiplying everything by the length of the vector which is 3, and not by 3000, 3500 and 4000.

Comment: does that make sense? I am not sure the length command should be used in any case

Comment: Well, check the location where that multiplication should occur and make sure it's indexed correctly.  Like I said I couldn't test this to make sure it works.  But I'm pretty confident that it should work.  Make sure you're using `number_panels(idx_number_panels)` as your multiplication value.  Not `idx_number_panels`